# What is the easiest way to solve: $\int\sqrt{4x^2+1}\ dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I've solved this problem with $3$ substitutions and it was tedious. Now I want to know is there better way with less steps ?

$$\int\sqrt{4x^2+1}\ dx$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you use some hyperbolic sine substitution?

Comment: Could you please include your initial substitution (of you solution)?

Answer (score 5):

hint...Try substituting $$2x=\sinh u$$

Answer (score 2):

Try a substitution of $x = \frac{1}{2}\tan(u)$.  Then use $1 + \tan^2(u) = \sec^2(u)$.

Comment: I did the same thing before and i get $\int 1/2 \ frac (1) (cos^3u)

Answer (score 1):

$\int\sqrt{4x^2+1}\ dx$

=$\int\sqrt{1 + 4x^{2}}\ dx$

= 2 $\int\sqrt{(\frac{1}{2})^2 + (x)^{2}}\ dx$

Put values in following formula and you have answer.

**$\int\sqrt{a^2 + x^2}dx = \frac{x}{2}\sqrt{a^2 + x^2} + \frac{a^2}{2}ln|x + \sqrt{a^2 + x^2}| + C$**

= 2$\left[\frac{x}{2} \sqrt{1 + 4x^2} + \frac{1}{8} \ln | x + \sqrt{1 + 4x^2}| \right] + C$

> Edit -

Thanks to @amWhy

Here are some formula's [you can see and learn.](http://www.rfcafe.com/references/mathematical/integrals-sq-root.htm)

Comment: Could you add the source of the image of which you copied?  You need to verify the given *formula*:  How did you obtain it?  Don't  you want to share how to go from step $3$ to the formula you give?

Comment: @amWhy I think you need to check the formula.

Comment: First of all I think adding photo of formula is not a crime here. Second thing if someone know the formula then he copy here. Third thing I think may be you want me to write formula instead of photo that's why I remove that and wrote formula.

Comment: No it isn't a crime, but failing to acknowledge or attributing to the source is really out of line, and failing to provide it even when requested in four comments is even worsel.  Thanks for the link you provided now in your post.  This will be most helpful to the OP.

Comment: And those who are down voting ever any user answer please give proper genuine reason.

Comment: What I asked from the very beginning, Kanwaljit, was that you provide the source of the formula you were using (or of the image) so that the OP can see it too, and perhaps also see an expanded version how to get there.  Using the image, or the formula was not the problem. All that I asked was to provide a link to the source. If you had done so after my first request, great. But you didn't, and so I was perfectly justified in asking again.  Now, I received two pings from your last two messages.  Please know that I did **not** downvote your answer.  (Didn't upvote it either).  Take good care.

Comment: @amWhy OK I understand now. From the next time I will always provide link.

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another way if you don't know/remember or can't use those formulas and substitutions mentioned in some other answers and comments.  Whether or not this is less tedious is subjective.

First integrate by parts with $u= \sqrt{4x^2+1}$ and $dv=dx$.

\begin{align*}
  I &= \int \sqrt{4x^2 + 1} \, dx\\[0.3cm]
    &= x\sqrt{4x^2 + 1} - \int \frac{ 8x^2}{\sqrt{4x^2+1}} \, dx\\[0.3cm]
    &= x\sqrt{4x^2+1} - 2 \int \frac{4x^2 + 1-1}{\sqrt{4x^2+1}}\, dx\\[0.3cm]
    &= x\sqrt{4x^2+1} - 2\int \sqrt{4x^2+1}\, dx + 2 \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{4x^2+1}}\, dx\\[0.3cm]
    &= x\sqrt{4x^2+1} -2I + \int \frac 2{\sqrt{(2x)^2+1}}\, dx
\end{align*}
In that integral on the RHS of the last line above, let $t= 2x$ so $dt = 2\, dx$.  Then
$$
  I =  x\sqrt{4x^2+1} -2I + \int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}
$$
That last integral above is $\operatorname{arcsinh}(t)+C$.  Finally, back-substitute $t=2x$ and solve for $I$.

(I know this also required a formula at the very end but I think that formula is more commonly known/used in calculus courses.  Depends on locale I suppose.)